# How long message can I send?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle, information-theory, bit-strings

I know the $n$-bit message ($M$).

I have to send it to the receiver bit by bit.

For each bit I can also send one bit of comment ($C$).

Before receiver gets the bit, he have to guess it($G$).

After all, $M$, $C$ and $G$ should differ only in $k$ places, ie:
$$||(M \underline{\vee} C) \vee (M \underline{\vee} G)|| \leq k  $$

Receiver and I both know the protocole of sending the message, so he can guess some informations basing on my comments.

What is the maximal length of the message I can send?

the only solution I've found is $n=2k$, which is pretty obvious (eg. in the first $k$ bits of $C$ I send the second half of the message). Is it possible to construct the protocole in the way, that it allow to send messages longer than $2k$?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the worst case of the "guess" has to satisfy the inequality? So in fact the receiver must be able to *deduce* a "guess" from the message and comment bits already received such that the inequality is satisfied?

Comment: Yes. The receiver have to guess $i+1$st bit basing on the $i$ previous bits.

Comment: No, that part was clear. My question was about whether you want a worst-case analysis.

Comment: Also yes. I want to be sure, that the inequality is satisfied regardless the message $M$